# for-in iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript

To the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>This.........</p>
<p>That.....</p>
<p>And yet .....</p>
<script>
x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (i in x)  
    document.write("..."+x[i].innerHTML+" "+i+"<br>");
document.write(x.length);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm getting the output

```
This.........

That.....

And yet .....
...This......... 0
...That..... 1
...And yet ..... 2
...undefined item
...undefined namedItem
...undefined iterator
...undefined length
3
```

rather than the following which is what i expect:

```
This.........

That.....

And yet .....
...This......... 0
...That..... 1
...And yet ..... 2
3
```

the **for-in** statement is supposed to iterate on **x** as many times as the length of **x**-- which is 
3 as the code itself is saying-- and terminate. what it seems to be doing instead is iterating 
on all the children of the node-- not just the paragraph tags 
returned by **document.getElementsByTagName("p")**.

this is either some subtlety i'm missing in the code, or a mistake in the JavaScript engine.

What's missing here?

Comment: You need a regular `for` loop.

Comment: Short answer: *do not* use `for..in` for iterating arrays or sequences. `for..in` iterates *properties* (which includes array indexes, but also other properties like `item` and `iterator`).

Comment: "or a mistake in the JavaScript engine" --- it's 99.9999% chance that *every error* you experience in next year of your career is your mistake, not ECMAScript implementation's

Comment: `the for-in statement is supposed to iterate on x as many times as the length of x` - Wrong. That is not what the `for ... in` statement means at all. It iterates over the keys of `x`.

Comment: Don't use for-in for arrays.  Also, don't use document.write(), _ever_.

Comment: @user2864740 the Q is why-- is it one of those loose constructs of javascript compared to those of the core Java compiler?

Comment: @user2864740 thx for the comment btw. it's explaining better than any so far including the answers.

Comment: @ashley it's part of the core language, but it doesn't do what you think it does :)

Comment: @MikeEdwards: There are legit uses for `document.write()` like conditional, synchronous script loading, and some other rare cases.

Comment: @ashley That question was not asked in the post. Anyway, the answer is [*because this is how for-in is defined in the ECMAScript specification*](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4). Also, Java and JavaScript (besides an unfortunate name similarity) are entirely *different* languages with *different* rules.

Comment: @Pointy looking up the keys Chris Hayes mentions. and no it obviously isn't-- as it's showing itself.

Comment: @ashley I don't understand what you mean. Chris Hayes's comment is correct: `for ... in` iterates through the enumerable property names of an object, in no specified order. Those will include the numeric property names as well as the non-numeric ones.

Comment: @ashley note that in the last four lines, the values of "i" are "item", "namedItem", "iterator", and "length".  Those are properties of the NodeList object.

Comment: @Pointy which is why i'm looking into Chris Hayes's. looking behind things helps which is what all of us shd do once in a while.

Comment: well-- dont think of everyone like yourself @zerkms.
nothing justifies your lines-- youre v.probably short for them even.

Comment: .. sry for getting back late btw. the mod seems ok w/your arrogance. so should be this - @zerkms.

Comment: @ashley: even though you don't like it - just take the point: in near future all the mistakes will be caused by you, not by JS engine.

Comment: @zerkms: nope, not really. look above-- also look around, expand your horizons some. helps.

Comment: @zerkms: sry, no further comments to you.

Comment: @ashley: what do you actually mean? You've made the simplest mistake and blamed JS engine implementation. Just read your question once again. And instead of arguing spend some time learning JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `for ... in` for arrays and array-like things like NodeList objects. Always use a numeric index.

The `for ... in` construct is for iterating through the enumerable properties of an object. Strictly speaking, it doesn't even guarantee that the numeric properties will be traversed in numeric order! Use a numeric index, or else convert array-like objects to real arrays and use `.forEach()` (in newer browsers):

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
[].slice.call(x, 0).forEach(function(value, index) {
  document.write("..." + value.innerHTML + " " + index + "<br>");
});
```

*edit* — RobG points out correctly that the `.slice()` trick won't work in IE versions before IE9.  It's easy enough to do the same thing with a simple `for` loop with a numeric index, so if you're worried about IE8 or below, just do that:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
  // whatever with x[i]
}
```

Really old versions of Mozilla, I think, didn't even support using array indexing with Node objects; you had to use the `.item( i )` method.  I don't think that's a serious concern for realistic new code however.

Comment: @RobG ha ha yes thanks, I just fixed that.  I don't think using "slice" on a NodeList has any bad repercussions; the MDN documentation includes similar suggestions in examples.

Comment: MDN is a community wiki for Mozilla browsers, I'm sure at least some of the authors are happy to publish code that will fail in IE. ;-)

Comment: @RobG well IE9+ can do it. I'm starting to live in the fantasy dream world of not worrying about Windows XP anymore.

Comment: —yes, IE9 finally starts to behave like a real browser but unfortunately (depending on whose stats you believe) IE8 is still used by about 12% to 15% of web users.

Comment: @Pointy: personally, I'll stop supporting IE8 when XP extended support ends - the vast majority of the IE8 users are on XP, and end users really should know better.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy—just because MS ends XP suppport doesn't mean everyone using IE 8 (and lower) will magically migrate to some other browser. According to some stats, 5% are still using IE 6 and mainstream support for Windows 2000 stopped in 2005.

Comment: @RobG that statistic is true, but a huge %age of those IE6 users are in China. Personally I work on web apps that have to do with US healthcare financial products, so Chinese web users are intrinsically irrelevant to me. There are all sorts of other niches where old browsers are really irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  document.write("..."+x[i].innerHTML+" "+i+"<br>");
}
```

Comment: yes, so the `;` after `i++` made an error, sorry. just edited.